# Deploying Windows Phone Application Does Nothing

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-phone

Error I'm getting:

> 1>------ Deploy started: Project: Butter me up, Configuration: Debug
>   ARM ------
>       1>Error: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>       ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>       ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Deploying does nothing. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this error before and could get to fix it. Here´s what worked for me:

- Reinstall VS 15 with latest UWP SDK
- Repair VS 15